# cannot set cuebanner for kryptontextbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, krypton-toolkit

I tried using the following code to set cue banner for a kryptontextbox

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       SetCueText(KryptonTextBox1.Handle, "Enter Name here")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module CueBannerText
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
    End Function
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As IntPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr
    Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501

    Public Sub SetCueText(hWnd As IntPtr, text As String)
      if Not hWnd = IntPtr.Zero Then
         SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
      End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

however, the text is not getting set. how do i fix this

Comment: Its `MultiLine` should set to `false`. And also it should be derived from `TextBox`. As an alternative solution you can paint the show the watermark using a `NativeWindow` by handling `WM_PAINT` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EM_SETCUEBANNER` is applicable on a `TextBox` control. `KryptonTextBox` in fact is a composite `Control` which contains a `TextBox`.

The `TextBox` is exposed using a `TextBox` property. You can use `KryptonTextBox1.TextBox.Handle` to send `EM_SETCUEBANNER` message.

To see the source code for components take a look at this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton). Here is a related part of code:

```
public class KryptonTextBox : VisualControlBase, IContainedInputControl
{
    //...
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        get { return _textBox; }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your compliments :) Feel free to notify me when you need more attention to a question. If I have anything to share I'll share. Taking benefit from the whole community is better than just one :)